# Match whitespace except a specific line that itself contain a whitespace

Tags: regex

I have this example:

```
ED Ess  Nb  Ip
```

I would like to capture all whitespaces except the two present between "Ess" and "Nb".

```
ED·Ess  Nb··Ip
```

Where `·` indicate what should be captured.

I have try:

```
(?<!Ess\s)\s+
```

But it does not work since the Negative Lookbehind itself contains what should be captured.

Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have to use both [negative lookbehind and lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check if `Ess` or `Nb` is nearby.

```
/(?<!Ess)\s(?!Nb)/gm
```

[Here is test](https://regex101.com/r/9Qu48E/1)

P.S. I might notice that there is an edge case where the regexp would capture whitespaces if there are more than two present between `Ess` and `Nb`.